# Php Mailer page not running with header("Location")

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send a mail after a successful registration but the mailer page is not loading or either not running completely and the control goes to the next location. I don't know why this is not working.

```
header("Location: ../../email/registration.php?name=$student_name&email=$email");
header("Location: ../../registration_successfull.php?name=$student_name&email=$email");
```

I even try the exec and system but they are not working , can anyone give me any solution.

Comment: you can only run one header; the last one takes over. You may also be outputting before header.

Comment: ##What is in $email? The hole email content? That wont work.## ignore it

Comment: Actually first I'm sending and email with some data and receiving it with get request and then redirecting the user to the next page.

Comment: The email code is really big and I do not want to paste it in it , so is there any method to run the email page and since no event is happening here so I don't think I can put the ajax here to do this job.

Answer (score 1):

you can only do one location-header. 
So what you could do is redirect to the `../../email/registration.php` , send email, and then from there redirect to `../../registration_successfull.php`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.